# Fetching unique records for through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I have following models

```
class Tale < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tale_moral_joins
has_many :morals, through: :tale_moral_joins
has_many :values, through: :morals
```

the following code returns duplicate ids. I know why, but I want to know how to change that and get only uniqs

```
tale = Tale.first
tale.association(:values).ids_reader # => [1,2,2,3,3,4]
```

even if i do

```
tale.value_ids
```

the same happens. 
I know that the tale first gets the related morals and for each of them the related values. hence duplicate ids. What can be done by way of configuration rather than use .uniq on the returned array

Answer (score 1):

tale.association(:values).ids_reader.uniq

For example

```
[1,2,2,3,3,4].uniq
```

This will return => [1, 2, 3, 4]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`distinct`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/distinct) on the relation to `SELECT` unique records (SQL uses `SELECT DISTINCT`):

```
tale.values.distinct
```

You can also use `pluck` with `"DISTINCT id"`:

```
tale.values.pluck("DISTINCT id")
```

This avoids an unnecessary `GROUP BY` statement, of which there can only be one per query.

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick:

```
tale = Tale.first
tale.values.group(:id).pluck(:id)
```

Records will be filtered by the database engine, not the Ruby interpreter. In most cases that is preferable.